# Do all CSS background properties and their values works in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml, cross-browser

Does all CSS background properties and their values works in IE6?

```
* background-attachment
* background-position
```

Comment: Note that the answers you are getting refer to CSS 2.x. CSS 3 will introduce more background properties and change existing ones in ways which are not supported by IE6 at all.

Answer (score 2):

See [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#color):

> background:    **Yes**
>   background-attachment: **Partial**
>   background-color:       **Yes**
>   background-image    :   **Yes**
>   background-position:    **Partial**
>   background-repeat:  **Yes**
>
> A value of "Partial" in a cell indicates that that feature is only partially implemented in that version of Internet Explorer. For more information, click the link to view that feature's reference page on MSDN.

**Update:**

As you edited your question, the two properties you ask for are those that are only partially supported. For more information, go to the site I linked to and check the properties.

Answer (score 1):

The following are fully supported in IE6 :

```
* background-position
* background-repeat
```

You may encounter some bugs when using the other properties. Check [this link](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2008/08/css-background-properties/) if you want more details about the different bugs in various browsers.

Comment: what is the problem with "background-repeat" ?

Comment: There is no problem, background-repeat is fully supported in IE6, as I said in my answer.

Comment: Well, event if MSDN states it as being "partially" supported, all values should work as intented in IE6.